# Change read order of hosts.allow and hosts.deny?

Tags: networking, unix

When deciding whether to allow or deny a connection, wrappers first checks each line of /etc/hosts.allow and then (if no match was found) checks each line of /etc/hosts.deny.

Is there a way to configure it to check those files in the opposite order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the allow/deny option:

```
sshd : client-1.example.com : deny
sshd : client-2.example.com : allow
```

in *hosts.allow* the syntax for both of the files are identical.